# Installing the Zerigo Addon causes an Application Error

Tags: heroku, zerigo

Just went to add the Zerigo addon to a new app in the European region on Heroku, but it fails:

From command line:

`$ heroku addons:add zerigo_dns:basic`

Gets me:

`Adding zerigo_dns:basic on unwalked... failed
 !    Application error`

And trying to install from the addons panel gets me:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Zerigo add-on is currently only available in the US Region.

Comment: how we do when in EU?